# How to pull SQL results into a dictionary list in python?

Tags: python

I am retrieving 3 columns from MySQL which represent one dataset. How can I pull those into a list of dictionaries?

My current code:

```
    test[row[0]] = row[1]  # row[3] also needed
    for item, url in test.items():
        print(item, url)
```

I would need 3 items instead of 2, but can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: Check out python [ORMs](https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since pulling three columns, I assume you know what they are.

So you can unpack your rows into dictionnaries, or even better namedtuples.

```py
columns = ["n", "c", "is_odd"]
results = [
    [1, "a", True],
    [2, "b", False],
    [3, "c", True],
    ]
```

With dicts:

```py
dict_results = [{c: v for c, v in zip(columns, row)} for row in results]

print(dict_results[1]["is_odd"])
```

With namedtuples:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

your_results = namedtuple("your_results", columns)

namedtuple_results = [your_results(*row) for row in results]

print(namedtuple_results[1].is_odd)
```